# Itunes Connect issue related to Screenshots

Tags: screenshot, itunes

I notice several issues related to screenshots and localized languages.  I have an iPad (only) app, English only .  Attempting to submit to Itunes I get 2 errors, one related to Localization (just English is localized) and 12.9 inch Display message - You must provide a screenshot fro the primary size of a device".  I have take new Retina screenshots (iPad Air 2) and loaded them (via my Mac) to the screenshots "other sizes" area as this is the only place they were "accepted" (dropping them in).

Are the above errors related?  If I fix the missing screenshot issue will the localization issue go away?  How can I generate a screenshot that will be accepted in the 12.9" app preview screenshot area?  Do I need to have a 12.9" iPad pro to do this (surely not)?

Sorry, I am lost with this, been struggling for a full day.

Answer (score 8):

In Xcode, set the destination for running your app to "iPad Pro" for the simulator ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qthFW.png)).

When your app is running in the iOS simulator, go to Window > Scale and choose 100%.

Then choose File > Save Screen Shot. Your screen shot will have the resolution of an iPad Pro and you can submit it to iTunes Connect. The localization error is probably related to the screen shot issue, so it should be resolved when you've uploaded proper screen shots.